# Should list data type be used rather than object with booleans in response

Tags: rest, architecture, api-design

Which option is better ?

(a) Use true/false values to indicate the parameter status.

```js
{
  "param1": {
    "clicked": false,
    "visited": true
  },
  "desktop_app": {
    "installed": true,
    "removed": false
  },
  "chekpoints": {
    "2021-W43": {
      "choice_done": true,
      "slide_in_seen": true
    },
    "2021-W44": {
      "meal_choice_done": false,
      "slide_in_seen": false
    }
  }
}
```

(b) Use list instead and exclude `false` params from it.

```js
{
  "param1": ["visited"],
  "desktop_app": ["installed"],
  "chekpoints": {
    "2021-W43": ["choice_done", "slide_in_seen"],
    "2021-W44": []
  }
}
```

Comment: I've only found this blog post about boolean type in api https://medium.com/geekculture/why-you-shouldnt-use-booleans-in-rest-apis-2747b187876c.

Answer (score 1):

As with many things in API design, the choice here is a bit arbitrary and the "best choice" will be at least partly a matter of opinion. The important thing is to be consistent in your choice and not mix-and-match your style (booleans in some places, flags in others).

When I'm faced with the se problems, I look at the code I'd have to write. For example, here's two conditionals in TypeScript:

```js
if (desktop_app.installed === true) { /* Do something */ }
if (desktop_app.includes('installed')) { /* Do something */ }
```

Personally, I think the boolean flags here are very useful and easy to understand, whereas the tag method is a bit more ambiguous and open to confusion. In other words, `desktop_app.installed = true` is clear and concise when writing code, though more verbose on the wire in JSON. `desktop_app = ['installed']` (or `desktop_app.includes('installed')`) takes me a moment to understand and might leave me wondering, "Wait, is this doing what I mean it to do?"

I'd go for the boolean flags in this case.